# Select range of cells with i integer

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to select a range of cells with i integer in it. Instead of selecting the entire row I want a specific range of cells. Below I am providing the code for selecting the entire row(it runs fine) and also the code I have written to select the specific range(it does not run)

**CODE for row**

```
With ws2
lastrow1 = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 4 To lastrow1
    If .Cells(i, "D").Interior.ColorIndex = -4142 Or .Cells(i, "D").Interior.ColorIndex = 2 Then
        If CopyRange Is Nothing Then
        Set CopyRange = .Rows(i)
        Else
        Set CopyRange = Union(CopyRange, .Rows(i))
        End If
    End If
Next i
End With
```

**CODE for range**

```
With ws2
lastrow1 = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 4 To lastrow1
    If .Cells(i, "D").Interior.ColorIndex = -4142 Or .Cells(i, "D").Interior.ColorIndex = 2 Then
        If CopyRange Is Nothing Then
        Set CopyRange = .Cells("A & i & ":F" & i)
        Else
        Set CopyRange = Union(CopyRange, .Rows(i))
        End If
    End If
Next i
End With
```

Comment: Missed a quotation mark - Change your one line to this: `Set CopyRange = .Cells("A" & i & ":F" & i)`

Comment: @JohnBustos you must use `.Range("A" & i & ":F" & i)` because `Cells` only accepts rows and columns like `.Cells(row, column)` but no ranges.

Comment: Guys still there is an issue and it does not run!

Comment: @PericlesFaliagas *"does not run"* is a useless error description. What error do you get and where? Or what happens instead of what you expect to happen?

Comment: It tells me that CopyRange is empty. I want to copy this range into another sheet after I create it!

Comment: what is the value of `lastrow1`?

Comment: the value is 733

Comment: But I guess the lastrow part is correct as it runs with the row input instead of range as I mentioned in the question

Comment: See if my answer solves it. • If not go through it step by step with F8 and see what happens (and check your values).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that `Cells` does only accept a row and column like `Cells(row, column)` so you need to use `Range()` for a range like `.Range("A" & i & ":F" & i)`.

Also you need to adjust your `else` part accordingly because you still use `Rows(i)` there in the `Union()`

```
With ws2

    lastrow1 = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 4 To lastrow1
        If .Cells(i, "D").Interior.ColorIndex = -4142 Or .Cells(i, "D").Interior.ColorIndex = 2 Then
            If CopyRange Is Nothing Then
                Set CopyRange = .Range("A" & i & ":F" & i)
            Else
                Set CopyRange = Union(CopyRange, .Range("A" & i & ":F" & i))
            End If
        End If
    Next i

End With
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have used offset and resize to get the range.

```
Cells(i, "D").Offset(0, -3).Resize(1, 6)
```